# Plot of the exponential function

Tags: c, arrays, loops, if-statement

I need to generate a plot of the function 
$$ y=\exp(-0.1x)sin(0.5x) $$
using an asterisks(*) for each of the points that makes up the plot such that the plot run vertically downward the page, with one point (one asterisk) per line.
Each printed line consists of appropriate no. of  blank spaces .

How shall I plot this function in C program . 
I am a beginner in C who knows only -  2 D arrays, 
Control statements ,Data input -output .

I dont know -Recursion ,functions ,etc. 
I dont know , how shall I plot such a function since i know how to plot pyramid ,rectangles,etc.

Comment: [google can plot!](https://www.google.com/search?q=plot+exp%28-0.1*x%29*sin%28x%2F2%29)

Comment: Starting point: declare a "2D array" of chars. Fill it with spaces. In a loop, for each x value generate the y using the provided function and set the corresponding element of the array to an asterisc. Print the array.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so here is a complete solution with a custom plotter in the terminal using `printf`.

On the top you have a bunch of defines which you can tweak to change the plot size, accuracy and limits.

There is an equation function which you can play with as well.

Compile the code using something like `gcc main.c -lm -o a.exe`.

You'll get something like this.

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PLOT_WIDTH (72U)
#define PLOT_HEIGHT (30U)

#define LIMIT_X_MAX (25.0)
#define LIMIT_Y_MAX (1.0)

#define LIMIT_X_MIN (-2.0)
#define LIMIT_Y_MIN (-1.0)

#define PLOT_POINTS (500U)

void print_plot(const bool plot[PLOT_WIDTH][PLOT_HEIGHT])
{
    int i;
    int j;

    for (i = PLOT_HEIGHT - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for (j = 0; j < PLOT_WIDTH; j++)
        {
            if (plot[j][i])
            {
                printf("*");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("-");
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
}

double equation(const double x)
{
    return exp(-0.1 * x) * sin(0.5 * x);
}

size_t get_plot_x(const double x)
{
    double xx = x - LIMIT_X_MIN;
    return (size_t)((PLOT_WIDTH - 1) * (xx / (LIMIT_X_MAX - LIMIT_X_MIN)));
}

double limit_y(const double y)
{
    double yy = y;
    if (y > LIMIT_Y_MAX) {
        yy = LIMIT_Y_MAX;
    }
    if (y < LIMIT_Y_MIN) {
        yy = LIMIT_Y_MIN;
    }

    return yy;   
}

size_t get_plot_y(const double y)
{
    double yy = limit_y(y) - LIMIT_Y_MIN;

    return (size_t)((PLOT_HEIGHT - 1) * (yy / (LIMIT_Y_MAX - LIMIT_Y_MIN)));
}

double get_next_x(const double x)
{
    return  x + ((LIMIT_X_MAX - LIMIT_X_MIN) / PLOT_POINTS);
}

void populate_plot(bool plot[PLOT_WIDTH][PLOT_HEIGHT])
{
    double x;
    double y;

    for (x = LIMIT_X_MIN; x < LIMIT_X_MAX; x = get_next_x(x))
    {
        y = equation(x);

        plot[get_plot_x(x)][get_plot_y(y)] = true;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    bool plot_area[PLOT_WIDTH][PLOT_HEIGHT] = { false };

    populate_plot(plot_area);

    print_plot(plot_area);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  I got  And I have done  similar to it.   https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/Ij8GiPMahM   . Yours is much better than mine.

Comment: Your answer has many stars in one line but we need to make only one star in one line.

Comment: @Doraemon Reduce the number of points. Also change the limits

Answer (score 1):

1. You want to plot the function `y=exp(-0.1x)sin(0.5x)`, correct?

   Then your first task would be to write the function.

   Call your new function from the C root `void main(int argc, char *argv[])` with some sample values to make sure your calculations are correct.  Don't work on the "plotting" part until after you're sure the function is OK.
2. Since you want to plot "down" (a line at a time), then you probably want to solve for "x", instead of "y".  Adjust your C function accordingly.
3. Finally, call your function in a loop:

   ```
   void main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
      ...
      for (y=0; y < nlines; y++) {
         x = myFunction(y);
         myPlot(x, y);
      }
      ...
   ```
4. Give it a try.  Please post back with any specific questions you have if you run into any challenges along the way.

Comment: I am not getting it, can you breifly explain it . Actually , I just started learning C     10-15 days before .

Comment: Doraemon - your next step is to write some code.  Try something.  *ANYTHING*.  Please update your post with what you've tried, and what you don't understand about it.